# Why does it say -jar is illegal argument when try to run java?

Tags: java, jar, command, line

```
Command line: java -jar myjar.jar

-jar: illegal argument
usage: java [-options] class

where options include:
    -help             print out this message
    -version          print out the build version
    -v -verbose       turn on verbose mode
    -debug            enable remote JAVA debugging
    -noasyncgc        don't allow asynchronous garbage collection
    -verbosegc        print a message when garbage collection occurs
    -noclassgc        disable class garbage collection
    -ss<number>       set the maximum native stack size for any thread
    -oss<number>      set the maximum Java stack size for any thread
    -ms<number>       set the initial Java heap size
    -mx<number>       set the maximum Java heap size
    -classpath <directories separated by semicolons>
                      list directories in which to look for classes
    -prof[:<file>]    output profiling data to .\java.prof or .\<file>
    -verify           verify all classes when read in
    -verifyremote     verify classes read in over the network [default]
    -noverify         do not verify any class
    -nojit            disable JIT compiler
```

Comment: What version of java is that? Add the output of `java -version`.

Comment: java version "1.1.8.16"

Comment: @F.Viki if that version is not a typo, it is really old and it's not supported anymore. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jre-137461.html

Comment: And it apparently doesn't support the `-jar` option. Why are you still using a JVM as old as that?

Comment: It was the problem, thank you so much :)